How to Extract Geolocation Data from a Video File Picked from Gallery using image_picker in Flutter?
I'm developing a Flutter application where users can select a video from their gallery. I want to extract the geolocation data (latitude and longitude) from the selected video file. I'm using the image_picker package to allow users to pick videos from the gallery. However, I'm having trouble extracting geolocation data from the video metadata.
I have tried the following methods to extract geolocation data from the video file, but none of them provided the desired results:
video_compress, exif, media_info, VideoPlayerController.
